# Responsive Issue - When browser sized to 991px the body width stays at 3109px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am in the midst of making http://masteringvoiceover.com responsive.

You can see my current progress here http://preview.j64e7zzvo82p4x6r4fdjze6piimmfgviwsruf9j89pidaemi.box.codeanywhere.com/

For some reason as soon as the browser is resized to 991px or lower everything will stay responsive but the  will stay at 3109px in width.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Some images are wider as the viewport its width, give the images a width of 100% when viewport is at 990px for example using media queries.

As MrEhawk82 mentioned it is a best practice to add height:auto; along with best cross-browser support.

Comment: to add to this your solution. for images, i would set the height to auto if using a width %'s